# How can I make the dreamweaver format the css file as sublime

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sublimetext2, sublimetext, dreamweaver

dreamweaver display the css file as this style

[image]

add the sublime display as below

[image: image2]

I suppose the format that sublime display is helpful to read the css file

Comment: you mean formatting or colors?

Comment: I mean by formatting

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at two different files. In Dreamweaver you're looking at `bootstrap.min.css`, which has been [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)), while in Sublime you're looking at `bootstrap-theme.css`, which has not been minified, so of course they're going to look different. Dreamweaver is using its "Live View" function, which is examining the files that are actually sent by the web server. Minified files are used here to save bandwidth. If you want to view/modify the file being displayed in Dreamweaver, open your project in Sublime and find `bootstrap.css`. If you make any changes, make sure you re-minify it so the changes are applied to your site. However, the way Bootstrap works, you shouldn't have to make any changes to `bootstrap[.min].css`, instead you can just override specific rules in your own `.css` file loaded after Bootstrap's.